# android sdk error while opening the project

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to import an Android code. While doing this it gave me an error about SDK path and once I pressed ok to solve that issue it didn't open the project. Can anybody help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Before you Open/Import your project, configure your SDK and JDK locations on the Android Studio, and then try to Import/Open your project.